# t-sql - select all combintations of groups of rows in single table

Tags: sql-server, recursion

Ok, I have a table like this:

```
ThingID  SubthingID ThingLevel
1          1        0
1          2        0
1          3        0
1          4        0
2         14        1
2         17        1
3         22        1
3        950        1
```

I need to select groups of subthings such that I end up with one subthing from a level 0 thing, and all the combinations of subthings, one each from the level 1 things. Note that each subthing belongs to its thing - they're not interchangeable. So there can't be, say, a combination of thing 2 with subthing 950. Also, things come in two levels - level 0 and level 1. A level 1 thing is also level 1, and a level 0 thing is always level 0 - really, it means that level 1 things can be combined with other level 1 or 0 things, but level 0 things can only be combined with level 1 things.

So the output would look like:

```
GroupID ThingID SubthingID  ThingLevel
1       1       1               0
1       2       14              1
1       3       22              1
2       1       2               0
2       2       14              1
2       3       22              1
3       1       3               0
3       2       14              1    
3       3       22              1
.       .       .               .
.       .       .               .
.       .       .               .
x       1       4               0
x       2       17              1
x       3       950             1
```

There are multiple level 0 things, each with one to many subthings. There are multiple level 1 things, each with one to many subthings.

Offhand it would seem like nexted loops would be the answer:

```
For each level 0 thing begin
    for each level 1 thing subthing begin
       etc...
```

But that's obviously not going to handle variable numbers of level one things.

Is there a way to do this with recursion?